# Display 2 tables into 1 gridview

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables (Table1 and Table2).

Table1 & Table2 have the same column names, but Table2 has a few extra columns than Table1.

Column Names as follows:

- Table1 [Name, Surname, Age, Gender, Height]
- Table2 [Name, Surname, Age, Gender, DateOfBirth, Origin]

I am trying to get the data from both tables into 1 gridview.

Ive tried using UNION ALL but it throws back an error because the columns arent the same.

Is it possible to join all these columns into 1 gridview and display the data accordingly?

Eg: Name, Surname, Age, Gender, Height, DateOfBirth, Origin

If so what would my sql query look like?

PS: I have 70+ columns in each table so individually selecting this is not going to work out

Comment: "... I have 70+ columns in each table so individually selecting this is not going to work out..." -- As of 2019 SQL still does not have any other way of specifying columns. You'll have to type them all.

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put null values into the missing columns and use `UNION ALL`

```
select name, surname, age, gender, height, null, null from table1
union all
select name, surname, age, gender, null, dateofbirth, origin from table2
```

As mentioned by @TheImpaler there is no way around then to select the columns by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER function

```
SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t2.Column3, t2.Column4
FROM (
   SELECT Column1, Column2,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) AS rn
   FROM Table1) AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN  (
   SELECT Column3, Column4,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column3) AS rn
   FROM Table2) AS t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
    Name, Surname, Age, Gender, Height,NULL AS DateOfBirth,NULL AS  Origin 
FROM 
    table1 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Name, Surname, Age, Gender, NULL AS Height, DateOfBirth, Origin
FROM 
    table2
```